# d3.on("mouseover") event does not work with nested SVG elements

Tags: javascript, events, svg, d3.js, mouse

I have a nested set of  elements (SVG). The root element is the graph, and the children are elements in the graph (lines, axis, etc.). Simplified example:

```
<g transform="translate(80,10)" id="mainGraph">
    <g class="Line">
        <path d="....."></path>
    </g>
</g>
```

My problem is that if I bind a mouseover/mousemove event (with D3.on("mouseover") for example) to the mainGraph element, it only triggers if I move the mouse over one of the child elements.

One of the things I read is that there is priority of later elements, so I added .style("pointer-events","none") to all child elements, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 15):

One approach is to add a rectangle filling the whole surface as the first element to catch mouse events that are not caught by elements added later:

```
something.append('svg:rect')
  .attr('width', width) // the whole width of g/svg
  .attr('height', height) // the whole heigh of g/svg
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
  .on('mouseover', function() {
      // do something
    }     
  });
```

I believe the `<g>` element (mainGraph in your example) is just a container, not an actual shape that can receive mouse events.

You might be able to add the mouse event listener on the svg element itself, but I don't think the `<g>` will work.

Comment: Using the `g` should work if you set its dimensions explicitly.

Comment: A `g` element (unlike a `div`) is just a shapeless container, and so has no dimensions. So, if you want the mouseover to apply to a rectangular area, this you’ll need to specify rectangular content such as this `rect`. However, one useful refinement is using fill: none and pointer-events: all styles.

Comment: @mbostock does it make any difference if using pointer-events directly on the element vs setting it in its CSS properties? Does a ```path``` element inside the ```g``` behave the same way?

Answer (score 6):

Apart from using a `rect` element, it should have a CSS property set like this `pointer-events: all;` for the events to be triggered.

Comment: Yes, to set the `pointer-events` is the key, no matter if it's nested or not. The default value will make it only accept events when `visiblePainted`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events.

Answer (score 1):

I also face the same problems.
The solution is to add the css property to parent element

```
pointer-events: stroke;
```

or

```
pointer-events: visibleStroke;
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a very similar issue. Was being caused by me declaring the event listener twice EG:

```
.on('mousemove', function (event, d) {
// Mouse event stuffs 
}
.on('mousemove', function (event, d) {
// Mouse event stuffs again (overwrites above declaration).
}
```

Fixed by only declaring one listener function per event instead of two.

D3 will not  warn you about being this stupid. So make sure you only are declaring each mouse related event listener once.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problems.
I had the following code

```
svg.append("rect")
        .attr("fill",  "none")
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("height", 20)
        .on("mouseover", (event, data)=> { console.log(data)})
        .on("mouseout", (event, data)=> { console.log(data)});
```

where **fill** attribute is set to **none**. Once I removed **fill** attribute or set it to **white**, events started working as expected.
So my new code looks like

```
svg.append("rect")
        .attr("fill",  "white")
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("height", 20)
        .on("mouseover", (event, data)=> { console.log(data)})
        .on("mouseout", (event, data)=> { console.log(data)})
```